# MSAL not returning access_code to a B2C client app

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

My PublicClient.AcquireTokenAsync is not returning an access_token, only an id_token. The POST includes the authorization code and my custom scope: scope=https%3A%2F%2Fmrochonb2cprod.onmicrosoft.com%2Fwebapi%2Fread_policies copied from the Value of the API scopes. I saw similar report here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/issues/27 . In my case the name of the scope (read_policies) is automatically converted by the portal to the above value which I copied to my scopes variable. This is MSAL.NET 2.7.0

Comment: Did you include the same scopes in the initial request to the authorize endpoint?

Comment: I am using MSAL, which orchestrates both calls. I checked in Fiddler and yes, the initial call does include the scope: GET https://mrochonb2cprod.b2clogin.com/mrochonb2cprod.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_basicsusi/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fmrochonb2cprod.onmicrosoft.com%2Fwebapi%2Fread_policies+offline_access+openid+profile&response_type=code. So does the subsequent POST.